# WSO2 api manager 4.1.0 gives "900763:No resources found::API must have at least one resource defined" error when updating sample api

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

After doing a clean install of wso2 api manager (via docker-compose - https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim) and deploying a sample API (PizzaShackAPI) I am unable to update that api via the "publisher api's" (PUT https://localhost:9443/api/am/publisher/v3/apis/:apiId).

Whenever I try to update the PizzaShackAPI I get the following response, no matter what property I try to update (e.g. description or maxTps):

Request Body:

```
{
  "context": "/pizzashack",
  "name": "PizzaShackAPI",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error",
    "description": "Error while updating the API : 56d3faae-67b1-43e3-b1c5-18e1b06fe724 - 900763:No resources found::API must have at least one resource defined",
    "moreInfo": "",
    "error": []
}
```

In api manager logs I get the following:

```
ERROR - ApisApiServiceImpl Error while updating the API : 56d3faae-67b1-43e3-b1c5-18e1b06fe724 - 900763:No resources found::API must have at least one resource defined

org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: 900763:No resources found::API must have at least one resource defined

at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.common.mappings.PublisherCommonUtils.updateApi(PublisherCommonUtils.java:283) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.common_9.20.74.jar:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.updateAPI(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:803) ~[?:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.updateAPI(ApisApi.java:1511) ~[?:?]

at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]

at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]

at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPut(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:234) ~[?:?]

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:684) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279) ~[?:?]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:58) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]

at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

Since this is the "sample api" it does have resources defined. I can also call those resources succesfully through the console in the devportal and even updating the api through the publisher UI works without a problem, only through the publisher api I'm unable to update, and get the error above.

Fetching details and updating other stuff (like the swagger definition, deployments or revisions) through the publisher api works without a problem.

I also verified that I have a valid token with the right scopes (If I remove the required scopes I get a different error response).

I'm unable to find anything regarding this error on the internet. Can you point me in the right direction as to how to solve this error? Any suggestions on how to further debug this issue are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the payload of does not contain the operations of the API. You can add the existing operations of the API to the payload in the update request.

Refer the documentation[1] for a sample payload.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v2/publisher-v2/#tag/APIs/operation/updateAPI

Comment: Thank you Heshan, it was indeed solved when I used the entire response body from the "Get" request. I was under the impression only the above props were required, as they are marked required in the same documentation you also "linked" and that all other props would only update when present in the body. Clear now I'll just have to send the entire "Get" payload to avoid any problems :).